# Update Chrome flag programatically using javascript

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, google-chrome, webrtc

I want to enable "chrome-wide-echo-cancellation" flag of Google Chrome programmatically. Can we do it programmatically and how?

Answer (score 0):

You can not. This is behind a flag because it is an experimental feature that is not yet ready for production and end users.
You can star the chrome issue for updates: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1215049